# C# Screen Capture and Streaming

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, screenshot, screen-capture

I simply want streaming capture screen with TCP protocol on C#.

```
private Bitmap bmpScreenshot;

private byte[] screenToByteArray()
{
    byte[] result;

    try
    {
        if (bmpScreenshot != null)
            bmpScreenshot.Dispose();

        bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width,
                       SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height,
                       PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        using (var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
        {
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
                                        SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            result = ImageToByte(bmpScreenshot);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR]screenToByteArray Error..{0}", ex.Message);
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}


private byte[] ImageToByte(Image iImage)
{
    if (mMemoryStream != null)
        mMemoryStream.Dispose();

    mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    if (iImage != null)
        iImage.Dispose();

    return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

I use that code part and I'm sending `screenToByteArray()` but I have a problem. If My screen does not have lots of image like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdOYB.png), Listener can see correct display, but When my screen has complicated image(s) like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j86ef.jpg) , Listener sees distorted display like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/978sv.png) .When my screen has any complicate image, listener can't see the whole display. How can I do that. Thank for your help.

**EDIT**
I share my tcp code below

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.109"), 8500));

while(true)
{
    try
    {
            byte[] sendData = screenToByteArray();
            socket.Send(sendData, sendData.Length, SocketFlags.None);

            sendData = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[ERROR]sendScreen Error..{0}", ex.Message);
        socket.Dispose();
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: The fix, don't use low level TCP, or if you do, write a correct implementation that can deal with the TCP correctly .

Comment: Are you sure your problem is not with your tcp code? It is a thing a lot of people get wrong fist try. See if you can make the image appear inside the progam saving it first to see if it is a problem with the image or a problem with the network code

Comment: "*It is a thing a lot of people get wrong fist try*", its a thing people get wrong constantly, and spend a long time getting it right, constantly failing at it and fixing issues

Comment: Sorry but why `ImageFormat.Png` ? What is saying that `iImage` is in format png? - Don't know if it makes any difference but I would change the line `iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);` to `iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, iImage.RawFormat);`.

Comment: Notice  the comment `<-- closing bracket for?` - can the bracket be removed?

Comment: @TheGeneral - the tcp any good? (see edit of OP)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - the tcp any good? (see edit of OP)

Comment: @RandRandom I tried `iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, iImage.RawFormat);` but does not work.

Comment: Don't write your own socket code for this, there are a gazillion edge cases in socket programming.  A good protocol choice for this would be grpc.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/basics?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. The streamed picture format has been changed.

```
        private byte[] ImageToByte(Image iImage)
        {
            if (mMemoryStream != null)
                mMemoryStream.Dispose();

            mMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            iImage.Save(mMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            if (iImage != null)
                iImage.Dispose();

            return mMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```